# How can I create a column of numbers that ascends after a certain amount of rows?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a column of scores going in descending order. I want to create a column of difficulty level with scale 1-10 going up every 37 rows for diffculty 1-7 and then 36 rows for 8-10. i have created a small example below where the difficulty goes down in 3 row intervals and the final difficulty '4' and '5' is 2 rows

```
In:
   score
0   11
1   10
2   9
3   8
4   8
5   6
6   5
7   4
8   4
9   3
10  2
11  1
12  1

Out:

   score  difficulty  
0  11      1  
1  10      1  
2  9       1 
3  8       2
4  8       2
5  6       2
6  5       3
7  4       3
8  4       3
9  3       4
10 2       4
11 1       5
12 1       5
```

Comment: Please provide proper logic behind setting values.

Comment: Basically I have 367 rows with scores in descending order. I want to create a column of equally spaced difficulty level that range from 1-10. 10 difficulty levels means 37 rows for difficulties 1-7 and 36 rows for 8-10

Comment: Are the lengths fixed?

Comment: No, I just want equal amount of scores in each difficulty level from 1-10. That seemed like the most logical split

Comment: Please provide sample input and output which covers all your assumptions and logic checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

count = (37*7) + (36*3)
difficulty = [int(i/37) + 1 for i in range(37*7)] + [int(i/36) + 8 for i in range(36*3)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'score': [randint(0, 10) for i in range(count)]})
df['difficulty'] = difficulty
```